# How can I receive data(url) from webpage loaded in uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, url, uiwebview

I've UIWebView with webpage loaded. This webpage is simple - one picture which follows somewhere 
**How can I receive this URL after taping for handling in xcode?** I don't want to open this link in the same web view(what is happened now). Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this delegate function.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

NSURL *regURL=[request URL];
NSString *urlString=[regURL absoluteString];


}
```